# Dynamically Finding File to Upload to Artifactory Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Groovy library that takes a file at a directory and uploads it to remote host.
The location of the artifacts to be uploaded changes dynamically. So I am trying to find the file based on regex. Here is the snippet of the code.

```
def file = findFiles (glob: '$WORKPLACE/**/*-${BUILD_NUMBER}-*/${file_name}.zip')
```

However, file parameter returns an empty list. Even though when I can see that the specific file I want to upload exists in the directory. 
Is there a way to find the path to the file and use that in the function?

**EDIT1**

I even replaced the `findFiles` with a simple `ls`. I see the error that `No such file or directory`. But when I execute the same `ls` with the same regex I do see the file on the file system. This file gets created during the previous steps in the pipeline. Why does the future steps cannot find the file?

```
def file = sh (script: "ls '$WORKPLACE/**/*-${BUILD_NUMBER}-*/${file_name}.zip'", returnStdout: true).trim()
```

NOTE: The permission of the file is 644 and it is owned by Jenkins user.

**EDIT2**

For some reason this works. This finds the file exactly. Why is this?:

```
sh '''
 ls $WORKPLACE/**/*-${BUILD_NUMBER}-*/${file_name}.zip
'''
```

**EDIT3**

I moved the regex out of the `findFiles` just in case the variables were not substituted correctly.

```
  def file_path = "$WORKPLACE/**/*-${BUILD_NUMBER}-*/${file_name}.zip"
  def file = findFiles (glob: file_path)
```

I now get the following error:

```
java.io.IOException: Expecting Ant GLOB pattern, but saw '/app/jenkins/workspace/job/**/*-21-*/file.zip'
```

The above seems to be ant pattern. Am I missing something?

Comment: first: `pu[b]lic`; also: what relevance does it have? If you don't use the function and it is not relevant to the error, then consider removing it - makes the question alot shorter; My _guess_ why the last example works is, that you use `'` single quotes, the `${...}` get replaced by the environment - `findFiles` most likely does not do that and if those vars are available, then using `"` double quotes for the `findFiles` should help (no jenkins user here...)

Comment: Thanks. Point taken. I removed the function. The variables actually get substituted fine. Even without the  `${...}`. I made the edit to test this. See the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. The path that `findFiles` can work with is relative. With the current directory being the workspace directory.

```
  def file_path = "*/*-${BUILD_NUMBER}-*/${file_name}.zip"
  def file = findFiles (glob: file_path)
```

Comment: But I guess it does not workd with `'` single quotes?